# ADODB.Recordset erro '800a0e79' Operação não permitida quando o objeto está aberto

Tags: sql, asp

ADODB.Recordset erro '800a0e79'

Operação não permitida quando o objeto está aberto.

/intranet/portal/sistemas/MAN6/includes/inc_cmbDropSituacaoReserva.asp, linha 12

```
<%
sql="select id, nome from matricula_online.situacoes"
ql=sql & " order by nome"

RS.OPEN SQL, CONN
```

%>

    Selecione...
<%
    bolExisteComp = false
    IF RS.EOF = FALSE THEN
        while not rs.eof
            if cstr(intCodReserva) = cstr(rs("id")) then
                strSelecionado = " selected"
            else
                strSelecionado = ""
            end if
            response.write "" & rs("nome") & " "  & vbcrlf
            rs.movenext
        wend
    END IF
    rs.close
%>

Answer (score 1):

Isso ocorreu por que o rs estava se repetindo no código mesmo que ele esteja dentro do include. Abaixo segue o código corrigido.

```
<%
sql="select id, nome from matricula_online.situacoes"
ql=sql & " order by nome"

RSAUX2.OPEN SQL, CONN
```

%>

    Selecione...
<%
    bolExisteComp = false
    IF RSAUX2.EOF = FALSE THEN
        while not rsaux2.eof
            if cstr(intCodReserva) = cstr(rsaux2("id")) then
                strSelecionado = " selected"
            else
                strSelecionado = ""
            end if
            response.write "" & rsaux2("nome") & " "  & vbcrlf
            rsaux2.movenext
        wend
    END IF
    rsaux2.close
%>